# AngularJS 1st ng-class works 2nd doesn't

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-click, ng-class

I have the following:

```
<div data-ng-controller="resultsController">
    <div id="DIV1" ng-include src="'views/sidebar.html'" ng-class="showSidebar ? 'open' : 'closed' "></div>
    <div id="DIV2" ng-class="showSidebar ? 'open' : 'closed' "></div>
```

And within ( ng-include src="'views/sidebar.html'" )^ i have the following div with ng-click which triggers the change of **showSidebar**

```
    <div class="panel-header top-sidebar" ng-click="showSidebar = !showSidebar; ">
```

**$scope.showSidebar = true;** is in the **resultsController** and when the **ng-click** is called the ng-class on DIV1 takes effect but doesn't on DIV2.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can solve this:

1.**Not a desired way**

Using `$parent` to access the parent scope.

```
<div class="panel-header top-sidebar" 
     ng-click="$parent.showSidebar = !$parent.showSidebar; ">
```

We only need to access parent for a primitive type but not for an object. So:

2.**Appropriate way**

Appropriate way is to have the flag `showSidebar` inside a model object on scope lik.

```
$scope.someModel = { showSidebar: true }
```

and then refer it inside the included page because when you ng-inlcude, a new child scope is created off of the parent. But in this case, since you are referring to the object reference, the changes will be reflected in child as well as parent scope.

Here is a [**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/wipu7wOV5L0KkMBaBlXF?p=preview). Click on text "Inside" to see the change.

Comment: The second way is also correct. Learn more about javascript's inheritance, it's the cause of many "errors" in Angular.

Comment: I am saying the same thing, second way is the appropriate way. On the other hand, is it fruitful to create an angular service only to handle a flag which toggles a class.

Comment: Yes I agree with your answer, I was more explaining to OP. You're right, I would only create a service if it's worthwhile to add more sidebar functionality and if some sidebar functionality will be re-used in other parts of the app.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful detailed explanation. Very interesting about  how to use an object reference which doesn't change

Answer (score 1):

`ng-include` creates its own `$scope` so your showSidebar doesn't propagate to DIV2 because it's outside it's scope. My advice: make a service for your sidebar. and include it in the right controller(s).

**EDIT**

You create a service called `sidebar` and inject it into your controller as such

```
app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', 'sidebar', function($scope, sidebar){
    //track sidebar
    $scope.sidebar=sidebar;   
}]);
```

That way you can give your sidebar properties and methods that you can access in your views.

Comment: Hi Nicolas, thanks for your quick response, how would this work? How would the service link in with ng-class?